# custom navigation bar in xcode is cutting the image

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

```
/*enter code here */    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"top-bar.png"];
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

// set the text view to the image view
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageview;
```

I am using this code for custom navigation bar but the image is cutting out . Although the image width is same as device width.

Any idea, how to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The titleView property only covers title area of the navigation not the complete navigation-bar.